# Web3J | Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol" not found: File not found

Tags: java, ethereum, solidity, web3-java

I'm trying create a simple NFT using Java Spring Boot with Web3J dependency. When I'm trying to generate the `.abi` file and `.bin` file using Solc compiler, I'm receiving this error:

```
Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol" not found: File not found. Searched the following locations: "".
 --> src/main/resources/solidity/nfts/SimpleCollectible.sol:7:1:
  |
7 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The message for this error is clear, I cannot import external file. How I could fix this without copying the required files into my project?

I am new in this topic and I want to integrate smart contracts with Java.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same Error I found one solution for this, but it also has some issues. After compiling it give abi and bin files for both contracts.

You can try this, Add an `openzeppelin` file path also in your command.

[Found solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70742806/cannot-generate-abi-and-bin-files-when-smartcontract-contains-the-openzeppelin)

```
solcjs ./node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol 
       ./src/main/resources/solidity/AddressBook.sol  --bin --abi --optimize -o 
       ./src/main/resources/out
```

-- The first path is the `openzeppelin` contract path and the second is the source file path.

Answer (score 0):

Normally your ide might have an option similar to this in vscode `Package Default Dependencies Contracts Directory`. if this configured successfully, import statement should automatically go inside `node_modules` and find the `@openzeppeling` dependency. If not you have to pass relative path in solidity code:

```
 import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
```